# mocha: how to run test result dependent cleanup

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

how to start some test-result-dependent cleanup in mocha?
e.g.

```
describe('some nice tests', () => {
  //cleanup functions
  let cleanup1 = () => 'cleanup1';
  let cleanup2 = () => 'cleanup2';
  let cleanup3 = () => 'cleanup3';
  let cleanup4 = () => 'cleanup4';

  afterEach(() => {
    //no universal cleanup possible
  });

  it('test1', () => {
    //if failed use cleanup1()
    //if success use cleanup2()
  });

  it('test2', () => {
    //if failed use cleanup3()
    //if success use cleanup4()
  });

});
```

one possible solution is:

```
describe('some nice tests', () => {
  //cleanup functions
  let cleanupAfterFail = () => 'nothing';
  let cleanupAfterSuccess = () => 'nothing';

  afterEach(function() {
    if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
      cleanupAfterFail();
    } else {
      cleanupAfterSuccess();
    }

  });

  it('test1', () => {
    cleanupAfterFail = () => 'what i need in fail case 1';
    cleanupAfterSuccess = () => 'what i need in success case 1';
  });

  it('test2', () => {
    cleanupAfterFail = () => 'what i need in fail case 2';
    cleanupAfterSuccess = () => 'what i need in success case 2';
  });

});
```

but it looks not as a proper way.

is there any proper way to do it? If yes, how it looks like?

i use mocha 2.4.5
chai 2.2.0
the tests are in real life with protractor e2e + chai-as-promised. But i think it does not matter in this case.

Comment: I wonder what did you come up with?

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko with the bad "possible solution". Even without currentTest.state, since i dont need it in my case anymore.